# MySQL impact of long query

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have 2 large table a and b,

Now I run a large query using a and b, for instance run it at 12:00 it takes 2 minutes to return result at 12:02. Each row of data in both tables changes every seconds.

My question is,

1. The result is based on the data at 12:00? If so, does MySQL needs extra resources to snapshot the data?
2. Will such a long query bring negative impact on insert, delete and update requests?

Comment: *The result is based on the data at 12:00?* Depends on current transactional level server settings - for example, does the dirty reads are allowed. *If so, does MySQL needs extra resources to snapshot the data?* No. If tables are locked then external operations are freesed until unlocking. *Will such a long query bring negative impact on insert, delete and update requests?* Depends on current locking politic. In general - true.

Comment: Look for "MVVC" in MySQL.